# What do the enum values of objLogicalDisk.DriveType in vbscript refer to?

Tags: vbscript, enums, disk, filesystemobject

so the following code:

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim colDrives : Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
Dim objWMIService : Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Dim objLogicalDisk
Dim objDrive

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    Set objLogicalDisk = 
objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & objDrive.DriveLetter & ":'")
    Log(objLogicalDisk.DriveType)
Next
```

is used to get the disk type of each drive on a system. What I want to know is, what do the returned numbers ('3','4','5', etc) refer to? Looking around on the internet I find different answers to what they should be on my system - according to the internet:

Unknown = 0

Removable = 1  ' Removable medium

Fixed = 2      ' Fixed medium (hard disk)

Remote = 3     ' Network drive

CDROM = 4      ' CD-ROM

RAMDisk = 5    ' RAM disk

and according to the data i've gathered so far, 3 = my Local C Drive, 5 = my local D (DVD) Drive, 4 = network drives.

If anyone can help clear up this ambiguity, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official WMI reference is in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572.aspx).

As for your question, the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173.aspx) class reference describes the following `DriveType` values:

```
Value    Meaning
--------------------------
0        Unknown
1        No Root Directory
2        Removable Disk
3        Local Disk
4        Network Drive
5        Compact Disc
6        RAM Disk
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this post looking for some examples of working with the DriveType property.

FWIW, while Helen clearly provided the right answer, I thought it was also worth noting that a likely reason the OP encountered some confusion in his results is because he was mixing and matching the use of objects from different interfaces.

He started with getting a list of drive objects using FileSystemObject, but then switched to WMI to get the properties he wanted from each drive object. The DriveType property values for the Drive object are different under FileSystemObject than they are under WMI.

The similar reference to what Helen provided for the WMI stuff, but for the FileSystemObject stuff is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243132(v=vs.60).aspx

```
Value    Meaning
--------------------------
0        Unknown
1        Removable Disk
2        Fixed Disk
3        Network Drive
4        Compact Disc
5        RAM Disk
```

His results would have matched what he expected if he'd kept everything in FileSystemObject, something like:

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim colDrives : Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
Dim objDrive

For Each objDrive in colDrives
    Wscript.Echo  objDrive.DriveType
Next
```